# @DataJpaTest for failure test cases

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can any give example code snippet on @DataJpaTest for failure test cases along with expected exception. @DataJpaTest by default applies transaction, then in which cases we need to use @Transactional(propgation=Propogation.Not_Supported). Kindly provide an a code snippet example with all the above. Thanks you in advance...

Comment: refer to [@Rollback](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Rollback.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where I have an entity `LearningContent` with a non-nullable name field which I do not set.

```
    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void failLearningContentMissingName() {

        LearningProgram learningProgram = new LearningProgram();
        learningProgram.setBusinessReference(new BusinessReference("hello"));
        final BusinessIdentifier bid = BusinessIdentifier.generate();
        learningProgram.setBusinessIdentifier(bid);
        learningProgram.setName(new Localized("hello.learningprogram"));

        LppIntent intent = new LppIntent();
        intent.setBusinessReference(new BusinessReference("intent"));
        intent.setName(new Localized("intent"));
        learningProgram.addIntent(intent);

        LppLearningContent learningContent = new LppLearningContent();
        learningContent.setBusinessReference(new BusinessReference("learningContent"));
        learningContent.setContent("Hello world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        learningContent.setDuration(5L);
        intent.addLearningContent(learningContent);

        learningContent.tag("meow");

        learningProgramRepository.save(learningProgram);

    }
```